# React Context mutation doesn't re-render sub-module

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I use the class-based approach to react, and try to avoid using stuff like Redux or Mobx. I thought I could get away with only using the context api.

In the `render` function of my `App.tsx`, I wrote essentially:

```
render() {
    const appContext = {
        modules: []
    }
    return <AppContext.Provider value={appContext}><Main /></AppContext.Provider>;
}
```

In `componentDidMount` of `Main.tsx` I send two http requests. The result of the first one sets the local state and the component renders fine. 
There is a sub-component to `Main`, called `Partner` whose render function is basically:

```
render() {
    let leadModule = null;
    if (this.context.modules.includes('crm')) {
        leadModule = <Leads />
    }
    return (
        {leadModule}
    );
```

The result of the second request arrives a second later, and it pushes data to the `this.context.modules` array. The array then contains `crm`, but of course how would React know to re-render the sub-component `Partner` and display `Leads`? Obviously it doesn't, as the `Leads` component never appears... Unless, by some miracle, the second request, that populates `modules`, finishes before the one that sets the state of `Main` and triggers the first render.

Is there a way to make this work without radically changing my approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually simple. I had to add two things to the state of my `App` component (the top level component): the module array as well as the function to modify this array. Something like

```
constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
        modules: [],
        setModules: (modules) => {
            this.setState({modules: modules});
        }
    };
}
```

Then pass this state as the value for my provider:

```
render() {
    return <AppContext.Provider value={this.state}><Main /></AppContext.Provider>;
}
```

Finally, the second http request mentionned in my question just has to call

```
this.context.setModules(modules);
```

...with the list of modules the request received as a response. And voila, the `Lead` module appears.

I feel quite stupid but I found the idea in this blog: [How YOU can use the Context API in React.js to pubsub](https://softchris.github.io/pages/react-context.html#second-example-%E2%80%94-a-cart)